# References on 'Raychaudhuri Equation'

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

I want to learn about [Raychaudhuri equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) and its applications. I already have looked into papers by Kar & Sengupta, Dadhich but I want more rigorous treatment than these papers. Would you please mention some references?

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 2 of Eric Poissons book, *The Relativists Toolkit: The Mathematics of Black Holes* apparently has a good discussion.

You might also find interesting [this](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/einstein/) semi-technical exposition by John Baez which is where I first heard of Raychauduri equation.